# Is "conhecer" pronounced precisely the way as if it were "conecer"?

Tags: português-europeu, palavra-para-ideia, pronúncia

In the likes of `espanhol`, the `h` makes the word sound a certain way and which is different as if it were `espanol`.

However, in the verd `conhecer`, for instance, does the `h` make any difference at all? It's pronounced as if there was no `h` in it, isn't it? Why is it there then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'nh' in European Portuguese has the same sound as the 'ñ' in Spanish. This causes conhecer to be pronounced differently from conecer (which is not a word in Portuguese). The answer given by the Brazilian also applies to eu-pt.

Answer (score 4):

The sound of *nh* is different from the *n* and so the *h* is indeed there for a reason. It is the sound that in IPA could be represented by /ɲ/, a nasal palatal either as a voiced sound or an approximant. In Brazillian Portuguese, the whole word could be pronounced as /kõ.ɲeˈseʁ/ (the pronunciation of letters such as the *o* or the *r* may vary but uniformly the sound /ɲ/ will be realized for *nh*).

In Spanish, this sound that we represent by the digraph *nh* is represented by the letter *ñ*; the pronunciation of *nh* and *ñ* are virtually the same in the two languages.

You may be interested in reading the Wikipedia pages on [Portuguese Phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology?useskin=vector#Consonants), on the [Voiced Palatal Nasal](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Voiced_palatal_nasal&useskin=vector) and on the [Nasal Palatal Approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_palatal_approximant?useskin=vector).

Comment: You've only added European Portuguese to the question tags, which I do not read when answering a question because I would never assume it conveys important information. I always mention Brazilian Portuguese because I do not want to extrapolate to other variants of Portuguese with which I am not familiar.

Comment: There are many great contributors here from Portugal, I am sure, who could answer questions regarding European Portuguese

Comment: Start to assume that it conveys important information

Comment: what motherfucker deleted my 1st comment?